# Pandas setting dtype from list

Tags: python, pandas, dtype

I am reading in a large file and to save on memory. I need to specify dtype for each column in the dataframe. I want to from a list I already created for the dtype.

```
import pandas as pd

headers=['Record Identifier','Respondent_ID','Agency Code','Loan Type','Property Type','Loan Purpose','Owner Occupancy',
         'Loan Amount','Preapprovals','Type of Action Taken','Metropolitan Statistical Area/Metropolitan Division','State Code',
         'County Code','Census Tract','Applicant Ethnicity','Co-applicant Ethnicity','Applicant Race: 1','Applicant Race: 2',
         'Applicant Race: 3','Applicant Race: 4','Applicant Race: 5','Co-applicant Race: 1','Co-applicant Race: 2',
         'Co-applicant Race: 3','Co-applicant Race: 4','Co-applicant Race: 5','Applicant Sex','Co-applicant Sex',
         'Applicant Income','Type of Purchaser','Denial Reason: 1','Denial Reason: 2','Denial Reason: 3','Rate Spread',
         'HOEPA Status','Lien Status','Population','Minority Population %','FFIEC Median Family Income',
         'Tract to MSA/MD Median Family Income %','Number of Owner Occupied Units','Number of 1- to 4-Family units']


dtypes=['int64','object','int64','int64','int64','int64','int64','int64','int64','int64','object','object','object','object',
        'int64','int64','int64','int64','int64','int64','int64','int64','int64','int64','int64','int64','int64','int64',
        'object','int64','int64','int64','int64','object','object','object','object','float64','int64','float64','int64',
        'int64']


df = pd.read_csv('2017_lar.txt', sep="|", header=None, names=headers, dtype=dtypes, nrows=100)

print(df)
```

The error: 
TypeError: data type not understood

Comment: Does it work with `dtype=dict(zip(headers, dtypes))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the parameter incorrectly.  You can only specify a single type name, or a `dict` that matches column headers to types.

This is clearly covered in the documentation:

> `dtype` : **Type name or dict of column -> type**, optional
>
> Data type for
>   data or columns. E.g. {‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32, ‘c’: ‘Int64’}
>   Use str or object together with suitable na_values settings to
>   preserve and not interpret dtype. If converters are specified, they
>   will be applied INSTEAD of dtype conversion.

---

Since you are passing a list, it is assuming the entire *list* to be the dtype, which is not understood.

---

Here is a correct usage.

```
import io
import pandas as pd

i = io.StringIO("""
1|2|3
4|5|6
7|8|9
""")

headers = ['a', 'b', 'c']
dtypes = ['int64', 'object', 'int']

df = pd.read_csv(i, header=None, names=headers, sep='|', dtype=dict(zip(headers, dtypes)))

>>> df
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9

>>> df.dtypes
a     int64
b    object
c     int32
dtype: object
```